# Encryption results different between Node (crypto) & Swift (CocoaSecurity)

Tags: node.js, swift, encryption, cryptography, cryptojs

I have read countless "encryption results differ between X & Y" but unfortunately have not been able to find a solution.

I am trying to duplicate the AES encryption of a string in Node based on some previously written encryption code in Swift using [CocoaSecurity](https://github.com/kelp404/CocoaSecurity).

I have both of them returning base64 values, but unfortunately they are not the same.

**FYI I added a "test" key, iv, and string as example, these are not the values I am using on my project.**

```
let key = Data.init(base64Encoded: "DqviM6rMaYF3kHymVTiis7MH7agLcFqmDoX085K7AWs=")
let iv = Data.init(base64Encoded: "zur4lDpQk4tFaqnEUYKD9A==")
let aes256 = CocoaSecurity.aesEncrypt("Testing1!", key: key, iv: iv)
let result = aes256?.base64
// result = nmvqDhE43gRQ1B0EWCu7vg==
```

And in Node I have written the encryption (using the same key & iv ... I have triple checked) like this:

```
const key = Buffer.from('DqviM6rMaYF3kHymVTiis7MH7agLcFqmDoX085K7AWs=', 'base64');
const vector = Buffer.from('zur4lDpQk4tFaqnEUYKD9A==', 'base64');

const encryptTool = crypto.createCipheriv('aes256', key, vector);
const result = encryptTool.update("Testing1!", 'utf8', 'base64') + encryptTool.final('base64');
// results = FabfCtSAAuiZ9K93wcHXYA==
```

---

I know there can occasionally be differences in the padding between encryption implementations, but I tried adding `encryptTool.setAutoPadding(false);` above and it would not run.

Are there any other options that could be set in the Node portion of this to ensure the same base64 string is returned?

**Edited above to include key/vector, input string, and result**

Comment: Would 'utf-8' that you set in Node part have some role to play ?

Comment: 1. Show test input and the results of each in hex.

Comment: @Roshith I also tried `encryptTool.update(text) + encryptTool.final('base64');` with the same output of `result`.

Comment: @zaph thanks for the tip about not using Cocoa. Also in regards to randomizing the IV, do you mean that the IV should not be the same for each string that is encrypted? How do you handle that when decrypting on the other side (i.e. an API)?

Comment: @zaph I found a [few](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30555982/1554860) [explanations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8041580/1554860) about the random IV. I also added some test data above as an example of what the results are.

Comment: Your node result (`FabfCtSAAuiZ9K93wcHXYA==`) is the result of encrypting “Password1!” with that key and iv, not “Testing1!”. If you want to compare node and swift results, make sure you’re encrypting te same thing in each!

Comment: @matt wow...i just realized that. Thank you so much. I spent too much time making sure the key/iv were the same and forgot to make sure my test strings were the same!

Comment: @matt feel free to post that as the answer and I'll accept, as that fixes the issue.

Comment: Don't use [CocoaSecurity](https://github.com/kelp404/CocoaSecurity), it is dated, there is no longer a reason to use NSData in Swift. Also the default is completely wrong, the IV needs to re random per encryption, not derived from the key.